# Using John Papa's AngularJS style guide, what is the proper way to declare data objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that I have an AngularJS data service that makes a call to the server and returns an object that can be extended with additional methods.  For example, assume the following function is part of an AngularJS service for something like NerdDinner.

```
function getDinner(dinnerId) {
   return $http.get('api/dinner/' + dinnerId)
      .then(loadDinnerComplete)
      .catch(loadDinnerFailed);

   function loadDinnerComplete(response) {
      return new Dinner(response.data);
   }
}
```

What's the best practice for a place to define the Dinner class?  Is that a factory in a separate file?  Do I define that in the NerdDinner service?  Or do I define that in the GetDinner class (assuming that's the only method that can create dinners)?

I did not find any specific reference to creating objects in the [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), so forgive me if it's covered and I just missed it.

**Edit**
I ultimately decided to accept [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34664619/320417) because it most matched my needs for a rather simple use case.  However, [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34664722/320417) is pure gold, and should not be overlooked.  If I chose to extend the functionality of my DTO with simple CRUD or additional server based operations, a $resource is a great approach.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, unless you are explicitly typing your objects (typescript) is the object even necessary in the first place?  I can't help but wonder if you are creating an unneeded and unnecessary dependency.

Comment: It makes some things convienient. For example, I could do something like dinner.hasReservations() rather than dinner.reservatons.length > 0.

Comment: The same functionality could also be created inside of a controller or a service however. I don't necessarily disagree, just pointing out an opposing perspective :)

Comment: Duly noted :) Always good to have devil's advocate to question the sanity of a plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where to place business entities (like Dinner) is not explicitly mentioned in John Papa's style guide (afaik).

If you want to go this route (using business entities and placing logic there), I should give each entity its own factory:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myDinner')
    .factory('Dinner', DinnerFactory);

  function DinnerFactory() {

    Dinner.prototype.eat = eat;
    Dinner.prototype.cancel = cancel;

    return Dinner;

    // Constructor

    function Dinner (data) {
        // this is just an example:
        this.time = data.time;
        this.location = data.location;
    }

    // Methods

    function eat() {
      // ...
    }

    function cancel() {
      // ...
    }

  }

})();
```

Then you can inject them into your controller or maybe other service objects, just using `Dinner`, and create a new `Dinner` object using `new Dinner(data)`.

You could also use a service, but John Papa discourages services, because they are too similar to factories.

Answer (score 4):

IMO what you are doing has already been done in `$resource` and restacular. You are talking about "defining data objects" (or, models in typical parlance). That said, defining each "data object" as its own factory is the way to do it, as per John Papa's advice regarding single concerns.

John Papa talks about this in the [factories section.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories)

If you want to work this out by hand, IMO you could define your models and append methods on each which would represent various crud operations. This is the pattern `$resource` and restangular (sort of) take.

```
//Dinner model as angular factory, each of these methods returns a promise

function Dinner($http) {
    return {
        create: function(route, body) { /** http.post */ },
        get: function(route) { /** http.get */ },
        update: function(route, body) { /** http.put */ },
        destroy: function(route) { /** http.delete */ }
    };
}
```

now your `Dinner` model has convenient crud methods built in so you could do

```
var dinner = new Dinner;
dinner.get("/api/dinner/1").then() //get dinner with id of 1
dinner.update("/api/dinner/1", {name: "burger"}).then() //update dinner with id of 1
```

Edit:

So if you want to create an object that isn't concerned with retrieving data, IMO you should create another factory that requires your model. This decouples your data retrieval from your data manipulation. In OPs original example, the data retrieval and manipulation are  tightly coupled.

```
function Meal(dinner) {
    //this.meal is the specified dinner
    this.meal = new Dinner().get("/api/dinner" + dinner);

    //some random build-in data manipulation methods
    return {
        getCalories: function() { return this.meal * 400; },
        getPrice: function() { return (this.meal * 100) + "$"; }
    };
}
```

Now that you've separated your data-manipulation into a separate object you can do something like this (this is a synchronous example though)

```
var mcdonalds = new Meal(/** specify which dinner */)
mcdonalds.getPrice() //$4.56
mcdonalds.getCalores() //9999
```

Comment: I like this approach, and it definitely answers some questions I had about using $resource.  However, I'm not looking to extend the object with additional methods that retrieve data from the server. If all the methods operated on the data already retrieved, how would that modify the design of the object?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I have used both `Services` and `Factories` for creating objects. From John Papa's style guide however:

> Services are instantiated with the `new` keyword, use `this` for public methods and variables. Since these are so similar to factories, use a factory instead for consistency.

Following the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), you should put it in a new `Service` or `Factory` not part of another.